# Requested the deserialization of a Lambda layer with a Python `lambda` inside it. you can pass `safe_mode=False` to the loading function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is a Flask project and keras model, I'm getting the following error when running

```
"C:\Users\winne\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\core\lambda_layer.py", line 394, in _parse_function_from_config
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Requested the deserialization of a Lambda layer with a Python `lambda` inside it. This carries a potential risk of arbitrary code execution and thus it is disallowed by default. If you trust the source of the saved model, you can pass `safe_mode=False` to the loading function in order to allow Lambda layer loading.
LOAD MODEL ...
```

when loading model using `model_from_jason` I defined custom object with `safe_mode=False` but still getting same error

```
class ImagenetClassifier(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('LOAD MODEL ...')
        with open('../Resource/line_model_predict.json', 'r') as f:
            self.l_model_predict = model_from_json(f.read(),custom_objects={"safe_mode": False})
        self.l_model_predict.load_weights('../Resource/iam_lines--12--17.373.h5')
        with open('../Resource/word_model_predict.json', 'r') as f:
            self.w_model_predict = model_from_json(f.read(),custom_objects={"safe_mode": False})
        self.w_model_predict.load_weights('../Resource/iam_words--15--1.791.h5')
    def predict_image(self, image_filename):
        try:
            with graph.as_default():
                pred_text_model_word, pred_text_model_line = predict(self.w_model_predict, self.l_model_predict, image_filename)
            return pred_text_model_word, pred_text_model_line
        except Exception as err:
            print('Prediction error: ', err)
            return (False, 'Something went wrong when predict the '
                           'image. Maybe try another one?')
```

Comment: Perhaps your can check this out: https://github.com/keras-team/tf-keras/issues/44